# Proving $\omega \times (-\omega \times q) = q$ with $||\omega|| = 1$ using matrix representation of cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cross-product, robotics

Define the matrix representation of the cross product as the following:

[image]

Define $so(n)$ :

[image]

And finally define the following Lemma:

[image]

*(Source: Page 26 and 28 of A Mathematical Introduction to
Robotic Manipulation by Richard M. Murray, Zexiang Li and S. Shankar Sastry)*

Using all of these I want to prove $\omega \times (-\omega \times q) = q$ when $||\omega|| = 1$.

Here I go:

\begin{align*}
\omega \times (-\omega \times q) & = \hat{\omega}(-\hat{\omega}q)\\
& = -\hat{\omega}(\hat{\omega}q) \tag*{Pulling a constant out of matrix multiplication}\\
& = -(\hat{\omega}\hat{\omega})q \tag*{Because matrix multiplication is associative}\\
& = -\hat{\omega}^2q
\end{align*}

Using **Lemma 2.3**, $\hat{\omega}^2 = \omega\omega^T - ||\omega||^2I = \omega\omega^T - I$ and so $-\hat{\omega}^2q = (I - \omega\omega^T)q$.

So we need $\omega\omega^T = 0$ to prove that $-\hat{\omega}^2q = q$.

$$\omega\omega^T = \begin{pmatrix}\omega_1^2 & \omega_1\omega_2 & \omega_1\omega_3 \\ \omega_1\omega_2 & \omega_2^2 & \omega_2\omega_3 \\ \omega_1\omega_3 & \omega_2\omega_3 & \omega_3^2\end{pmatrix}$$

However this matrix is not 0 unless all components of $\omega$ are 0, which violates $||\omega|| = 1$ so we have a contradiction. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It only works if the dot-product $\omega.q=0$.  Try to find the spot in your proof where that would be used

Comment: Ah yes, $(I - \omega\omega^T)q = Iq - \omega\omega^Tq = Iq = q$. Thank you very much!